# Problem while importing opencv python package in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, opencv, python

I have python 3.8. While working a new project in PyCharm, there was a problem while importing opencv package. I tried multiple solutions but was unable to fix the issue. Here are the screenshots of the same. [Screenshot of command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oA6be.jpg)

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVqP1.jpg)

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04rkD.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your question by replacing screenshots with actual text.  Not only do links die, but it poses problems for the visually impaired.

Comment: I don't really know what the problem here is, but it looks like the next thing to try to be to specify to pycharm that you want the _version_ of opencv that you already _do_ have installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to install *opencv* using the command line as showed in the first screenshot, I suggest you to use the same virtualenv (or python interpreter) in PyCharm.

Basically in PyCharm is possible to configure a python interpreter in order to do not install again each package. 
I guess that the best approach is to prepare a virtualenv and to use it in PyCharm.

Anyway, to configure the python interpreter in PyCharm you should click on:

```
File > Settings > Project > Project Interpreter
```

Here you should be able to see in the top of the window the current python interpreter. To change it, simply click on the gear icon and then on *Show all*.

If the right one is not present, click on the plus icon and then search it using the *Existing environment* option.

**Note**
Looking at your screenshot, seems that you are **not** using a virtualenv but the system interpreter. If this is correct, when you have to add the new python interpreter, choose the *System Interpreter* option on the left of the window.

Once added the correct python interpreter, you should be able to import and use *opencv* in PyCharm.